# Automatically sync Nautilus file bookmarks between laptop and desktop

Tags: nautilus, sync, dropbox

I work on both a laptop and desktop, both running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. As part of my workflow, I keep a changing lineup of folders bookmarked in Nautilus for quick access.

What I would like to be able to do is to have this lineup automatically sync between the laptop and desktop. Thus if I add or delete a bookmark on the desktop, the same change occurs on the laptop the next time I boot it up, and vice-versa.

Just to be clear, this relates to the folder bookmarks, not the Places (Desktop, Documents, Music, etc) bookmarks. I have no need to change the Places bookmarks.

It occurs to me that I could perhaps create the bookmarks file in Dropbox, and use the Dropbox automatic update functionality, along with links to that file from each of the computers. But I could use some expert help in determining how to go about this, and in how many places this updating would need to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarks are stored in `.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`. So one solution could be to place that file on your Dropbox, and then place a symbolic link in `.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` in each of your machines pointing to your file stored in Dropbox.

```
mv  ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks_BKP
ln -s ~/Dropbox/bookmarks ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

Comment: +1. Wouldn't it be nice though to also synchronize login keys for FTP sites? In other words, to have the Seahorse repository in Dropbox (or any other cloud service)?